# Pandas Drop partial duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dfs:

df1:

```
    x  y  z
0   1  2  r
1   a  c  2
2  22  g  d
```

df2:

```
    x  y  z
0   1  2  r
1   a  b  2
2   3  g  d
```

I want to drop when column `y` and `z` are duplicated.

Desired result:

```
        x  y  z
    1   a  c  2
```

Because df1 and df2 both have same values in column `y` and `z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.merge` you can do

```
In [266]: dff = df1.merge(df2, on=['y', 'z'], how='left',  indicator=True,
                          suffixes=['', 'right'])

In [267]: dff.loc[dff['_merge'].eq('left_only'), ['x', 'y', 'z']]
Out[267]:
   x  y  z
1  a  c  2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 cols=['y','z']#columns to check for having same value
 df1[~(df1[cols]==df2[cols]).all(axis=1)]#extracting the rows where x and y are `not equal(~)` in both dataframes
```

Comment: Code only answers often don't help the OP understand the solution - please add some explanation.

Comment: Edited, please check now

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be

```
df1[df1.merge(df2, 'left', ['y', 'z']).x_y.isnull()]
```

Or, somewhat more low-key,

```
df1[(df1[['y', 'z']] != df2[['y', 'z']]).any(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve it is using `loc`

```
pd.DataFrame(df1.loc[(df1.y != df2.y) | (df1.z != df2.z)])
```

Output

```
    x  y  z
1   a  c  2
```